# Suppose $f: [a, b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is continuous, differentiable in all Points of $(a, b)$ and $f (a) = f (b) = 0$.

Tags: real-analysis

I have to prove that for every real $λ$ there exists a $c\in(a,b)$ such that $f'(c)= λf(c)$. I was trying  to prove the equation with an integral factor, I have $f'(c)-λf(c)=0$ so $M(x)=e^{-λc}$ and applying the Rolle's theorem I obtain that $f(c)=0$. I am very confused. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Apply Rolle's theorem to $\phi(x) = e^{-\lambda x} f(x)$. And learn how to use MathJax.

Answer (score 0):

Your idea is on the right track.
Consider the function
$$
g(x) := f(x)\, e^{-\lambda x} 
$$
and apply Rolle's theorem to $g$.